# How do I get JBox2d Body size

Tags: java, processing, jbox2d

I can easily get the position of the body but assuming it is a box, how do I determine the coordinates of the box so I can display it?

Just to get it to display, I hard-coded it to a 10 x 10 but if I'm drawing a wall, it should be tall while a moving platform should be much smaller and wider.

```
public void draw() {
    if (bodySocket.isConnected()) {
        world = JSONObject.parse(getWorld());
    } else { System.exit(1); }
    background(100);
    Iterator<?> keys = world.keyIterator();
    String key;
    JSONObject body;
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        key = (String)keys.next();
        body = world.getJSONObject(key);
        rectMode(PApplet.RADIUS);
        fill(255, 100);
        rect(body.getFloat("x"), fieldBottom - body.getFloat("y"), 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `Fixtures` class in `org.jbox2d.dynamics`. It's used to attach collision shapes to bodies.
Just by looking at the source code I guess you can use `Shape shape = body.m_fixtureList.m_shape` to get the first Shape of a body. You'll likely want to use a loop though unless you're absolutely sure that you will newer combine two shapes into a single body.